# C language policy on Pre-increment and Post-increment

Tags: c

Consider the following code-snippet in C:

```
int v = 10;
int z = v;
v = v++ + ++v;
printf("v = %d\n",v); // gives 23
printf("z = %d\n",z++ + ++z); // gives 22
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Because of [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point#Sequence_points_in_C_and_C.2B.2B), missing sequence point.